# What is the return type for function 'convert' with a null expression

Tags: sql, sql-server

What is the return type when the SQL `convert` function receives a `null` expression?

```
convert(decimal(8,3), NULL)
```

The `null` would come from a field.

Comment: It is `decimal(8, 3)`.  That is what the expression returns, regardless of whether or not the value is `NULL`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is a `decimal(8,3)`. It will always be since you called `convert`.

As proof, execute this:

```
select convert(decimal(8,3), NULL) y into z
```

It creates a table `z` based on your `convert` function. If you look up the definition of that table, you would see column `y` has data type `decimal(8,3)`.